# ECMAScript import

Tags: ecmascript-6, импорт

Пишу расширения для `chrome`.

Возникла проблема с импортом одного из другого:

**requests.js**

```
export function makePostWJson(data, url){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let body = JSON.stringify(data);
    xhr.open("POST", 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(body);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        return xhr.responseText
    }
}
```

**groups.js**

```
import {makePostWJson} from "./requests";

function is_trusted(urls){
    return makePostWJson(urls, '...');
}
```

На что я получаю уверенную ошибку:

```
groups.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

**requests.js** и **groups.js** находятся в одной директории.

Вообще не понимаю суть импортов в `ECMAScript`.

Нашел [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540318/how-to-import-modules-in-ecmascript-6), но он ясности не добавил.

**UPD:**

#### Основной вопрос:

Как импортнуть  функцию `lol` из `A.js` в `B.js`?

Comment: чтобы браузер понял что это модуль - нужно это указать. Для обычных скриптов - type="module" в теге script, для расширений возможно это пока не работает. Пример обхода: https://medium.com/@otiai10/how-to-use-es6-import-with-chrome-extension-bd5217b9c978

Comment: @Grundy, да, про тег слышал. Но все таки как импортнуть из `A.js` функцию `lol` в `B.js`?

Comment: _как импортнуть из A.js функцию lol в B.js_ - именно так, как ты уже делаешь. Не работает это только из-за способа запуска. Если ты будешь запускать это внутри тегов с нужным атрибутом - все будет работать. Если ты будешь запускать внутри nodejs - все будет работать. Но ты запускаешь как обычный скрипт, поэтому и не работает.

Comment: @Grundy, прочитал медиум. Спасибо.